# Linker error from homebrew installing php when running make

Tags: php, macos, installation, makefile, homebrew

I'm attempting to install php and php-cgi with Homebrew.

```
brew install https://github.com/ampt/homebrew/raw/php/Library/Formula/php.rb
```

Using this method returns the following errors.

```
==> make
clang: clangerror: : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)error: 
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1
```

I've updated Homebrew, and the XCode command line tools. The only warning `brew doctor` gives me is that a few Python "config" scripts exist outside my system or Homebrew directories.

Anyone know what the issue could be? Where can I look for more detailed error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the ampt tap, when I grabbed php I used the josegonzalez tap. You could try that.

```
$ brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
```

You can also get more information by using the -vd options to brew install.

```
$ brew install -vd https://github.com/ampt/homebrew/raw/php/Library/Formula/php.rb
```

I just unlinked my 5.3.13 php from josegonzalez and ran the above command. With the -vd I can see the ./configure command run and all the output from it as well as the commands make invokes and compiler output. Whew, this is taking a while to build.

It does fail for me with this output

```
==> cp ./php.ini-production /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.10/etc/php.ini
cp ./php.ini-production /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.10/etc/php.ini 
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.10/etc/php.ini: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:553:in `system
```

Looks like the Formula never creates ${prefix}/etc. I blame the formula. Try josegonzalez tap.

```
$ rm /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/php.rb 
$ brew tap jozegonzalez/homebrew-php
$ brew install php53
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I reached this conclusion myself.

Answer (score 0):

As a [comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1931#issuecomment-125519721) on homebrew-php repository just force link libxml2

```
brew link libxml2 --force
```